# ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext. java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: Service 'sparkDriver' failed

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have install below setup with version:
Hadoop version 1.0.3 
java version "1.7.0_67" 
Scala version 2.11.7 
Spark version 2.1.1.

getting below error, can any one help me this.

```
root@sparkmaster:/home/user# spark-shell
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
17/07/05 01:07:35 WARN SparkContext: Support for Java 7 is deprecated as of Spark 2.0.0
17/07/05 01:07:36 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/07/05 01:07:37 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.

17/07/05 01:07:37 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: Service 'sparkDriver' failed after 16 retries (starting from 0)! Consider explicitly setting the appropriate port for the service 'sparkDriver' (for example spark.ui.port for SparkUI) to an available port or increasing 


<console>:14: error: not found: value spark
       import spark.implicits._

<console>:14: error: not found: value spark
       import spark.sql


Using Scala version 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, Java 1.7.0_67)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala>
```

Comment: Can you please upgrade to Java 8 to get rid of _"WARN SparkContext: Support for Java 7 is deprecated as of Spark 2.0.0"_ and start over?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

There are a few different solutions

1. Get your hostname

   ```
   $ hostname
   ```

   then try to assign your host name

   ```
   $ sudo hostname -s 127.0.0.1
   ```

   Start `spark-shell`.
2. Add your hostname to your /etc/hosts file (if not present)

   ```
   127.0.0.1      your_hostname
   ```
3. Add env variable

   ```
   export SPARK_LOCAL_IP="127.0.0.1" 

   load-spark-env.sh
   ```
4. Above steps solved my problem but you can also try to add

   ```
   export SPARK_LOCAL_IP=127.0.0.1
   ```

   under the comment for local IP on template file `spark-env.sh.template` (`/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.1.0/libexec/conf/`)

   and then

   ```
   cp spark-env.sh.template spark-env.sh
   spark-shell
   ```
5. If none of the above fixes, check your firewall and enable it, if not already enabled

Comment: Step 4 helped to fix my issue. Thanks!

Comment: Step 3 worked for me!

Comment: step 2 worked for me.

Comment: Step 1 worked for me! 
In my case it was Cisco AnyConnect preventing host binding with this error:
ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address: Service 'sparkDriver' failed after 16 retries (on a random free port)! Consider explicitly setting the appropriate binding address for the service 'sparkDriver' (for example spark.driver.bindAddress for SparkDriver) to the correct binding address.
 at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)

Answer (score 20):

Add `SPARK_LOCAL_IP` in `load-spark-env.sh` as

```
export SPARK_LOCAL_IP="127.0.0.1"
```

The `load-spark-env.sh` file is located in `spark/bin` directory

Or you can add your `hostname` in `/etc/hosts` file as

```
127.0.0.1   hostname
```

You can get your `hostname` by typing `hostname` in terminal

Hope this solves the issue!

Comment: Underrated answer

Comment: Do as the @koiralo says or suffer forever. Do both things not just one (edit load-spark-env.sh and /etc/hosts). I was about to go into depression.

Comment: In case you are running on a company server, In my case, host_ip was culprit. You can also use virtual ip in place of 127.0.0.1 but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 10):

- Had similar issue in my IntelliJ

  Reason : I was on cisco anyconnect VPN

  Fix : disconnected from the VPN, this issue did not appear

Comment: I'm also on Intellij and VPN... however I do need my VPN. I tried setting *Allow local (LAN) access when using my VPN (if configured)*. And it worked.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using PulseSecure which does not support this option for Allow local (LAN). So, have to disable VPN when working on Intellij IDE/PyCharm for SparkSession to work.

Comment: I had this issue with Cisco AnyConnect VPN but explicitly setting my hostname to 127.0.0.1 in /etc/hosts fixed the issue.

Comment: I was wondering why sometimes it worked and sometimes it didn't, then I noticed that I was on VPN. Thank you, you saved much of my time

Answer (score 2):

1. in your terminal  by typing `hostname` you can have a look at your current hostname.
2. `vim /etc/hosts` and set the hostname you get just now to your exact ip or 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

**When ever you will switch network while working with spark,
It happens due to network switch.**

**for instant fix you have to add "spark.driver.bindAddress" in "localhost" mode or "127.0.0.1" in your spark application**

```
// Create a SparkContext using every core of the local machine
val confSpark = new SparkConf().set("spark.driver.bindAddress", "localhost")
val sc = new SparkContext("local[*]", "appname", conf = confSpark)
```